# If we assume all web browsers understand the <script> defer attribute, is it better just to put the linked script in the head with the defer?

Tags: javascript, script-tag, web-performance

If we compare these two options for a webpage and linked JavaScript files:

1. putting all `<script src="...">` near the end of the webpage, versus
2. putting them in the `<head>` section but use `<script defer src="...">`

and if [the mechanism of how `defer` works is as described in this page](https://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html), [this other page](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-defer/), [on Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script), and that [`defer` is supported in almost all modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=script-defer), then isn't it just better to use Option #2 above?

The reason is, Option 1 and 2 would work exactly the same, except for Option #2, the download of the JavaScript file can be parallel with the parsing (and rendering) of the HTML file.  So if the download time is 0.2s or 0.5s, this time could be saved.  This is true for SPA (Single Page Application) or for old fashion webpages if the JS adds elements to the page or kick-starts any dynamic or interactive elements in the page.

The only exception would be, if the browser is smart enough that, before parsing the whole HTML file in Option 1 above, it already "gathers" all JS file URLs and silently download them before the HTML file is parsed to the end or to the point of the `<script>` tag. But this will make Option 1 and 2 work exactly the same, so Option 2 would still be faster for browsers that doesn't do this?

P.S. having said that, I think there is one catch: since HTTP/1.1 specification recommends browsers should download at most 2 items from the same hostname at a time, so if the JS file is being downloaded and taking up one spot, some image files can be slower to arrive. (if the JS and images come from the same hostname)

Comment: The delay between the initial content response (eg, the beginning of the `<!DOCTYPE`) and the `<script>` at the bottom of the page *may* be nothing at all, if the page is small. But for large pages, putting the `<script>` in the head sure *sounds* like it'd be better in most cases, as your question says

Comment: So your question isn't really based on an existing problem with source code but to seek advince/opinions oh a best/better method?

Comment: @NewToJS Sounds like "Is there any disadvantage to X over Y?" It's a fair question, The *existence* of a possible disadvantage isn't opinion-based

Comment: It's about when the browser starts to download the script. At end, it'll delay until all HTML content is nearly parsed, and on top, it'll start download immediately when it parses the HEAD tag. If you have a large script file, it may be better to download the script as early as possible. If you also have a large HTML content and put the script at the end of the BODY, you would be delaying the download to complete twice.

Comment: If "almost" is good enough for you, maybe you can take into account also http2. Then all that "http/1.1 parallel gotchas" don't have to bother you..

Comment: Good to read: https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-defer/

Answer (score 1):

You’ve spotted the problem in your last paragraph.

In terms of JavaScript *execution* putting `defer` scripts in head or at bottom has little difference (though [it’s different for `async` scripts](https://calendar.perfplanet.com/2016/prefer-defer-over-async/)). However do be aware that defer scripts execute in order so any other defer script in middle of the page will execute after defer scripts in the head and before defer scripts at the bottom of the page. Usually when using defer you don’t care about the execution time but if there are dependencies then ordering can be important (i.e. loading jQuery before a script that needs jQuery) and `defer` honours ordering (where as `async` does not).

But yes downloads will cause other elements to suffer. Yes the spec recommends two connections are most, but in reality [most browsers use 6 connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser) for HTTP/1.1. This means if your low-priority, `defer` scripts are using one of those there’s only 5 connections left for everything else on that page. It is likely there are higher priority resources on the page than `defer` scripts so this is wasteful.

Browsers will scan ahead in the HTML to get a list of all the resources, and assign a priority to each resource (which will be low for `defer` scripts) but at the same time the browser will start taking items off the top of this prioritised queue and a low-priority `defer` script in the head may be started on before the other resources are seen. And because of this “preload scanner”, any benefit of putting `defer` scripts in the head is minimal. The browser will still see it and request it when it can. Yes it’ll take slightly longer to see it when at the bottom (particularly for large pages that might take a while to fully download) but it’ll still see it as soon as the HTML is downloaded in its entirety, even if it’s still processing scripts and other resources on the page so hasn’t got to the end of the HTML.

In an HTTP/2 world, where there is not 6-connection limit you may think this doesn’t matter as much, but it often does. Partly because the connection limit is not completely unlimited (100 or 128 parallel streams are common limits on HTTP/2 servers) but more so because bandwidth is not completely unlimited and so download contention is a real thing. HTTP/2 has the concept of prioritisation so in theory should be able to handle this well, but [in practice HTTP/2 prioritisation is often poorly implemented on servers and surrounding infrastructure](https://github.com/andydavies/http2-prioritization-issues#cdns--cloud-hosting-services) that you can’t depend on this.

[Patrick Meenan has an awesome talk about how browsers load resources, particularly touching on the HTTP/2 issues](https://m.youtube.com/channel/UCCxyrtvl3MpqPA10AyrcB0g). Well worth a watch if interested in this sort of thing.

So, in summary, I would still keep defer scripts to the bottom of the page for now.

Comment: I think Google bots also use HTTP/1, and they don't exectue the js, so the first print time will be longer and effect your SEO

Comment: GoogleBot uses HTTP/2 where supported as of last year (https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2020/09/googlebot-will-soon-speak-http2) and it does execute JS too.

Comment: Only selected pages, and the JS loading is also only partially as far as I understood